# Can someone with > 15 karma up-vote a few of the decent questions? Karma needed to bootstrap participation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's not possible to vote for questions or answers without first having 15 karma. However since no question has been up-voted the vast majority of users are unable to participate in voting.

According to the user list there are only 6 people who can currently vote:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/users/

I know the gazebo devs are very busy. If the rest of us can vote we'll be able to help tend to answers.gazeboim.org and relieve the burden a bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/300/can-someone-with-%3E-15-karma-up-vote-a-few-of-the-decent-questions?-karma-needed-to-bootstrap-participation./) by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 283 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just passed the threshold so I was able to do this myself.  The current number of people who can vote is now 15. Hopefully that will quickly kickstart participation.

Those with karma. Do your best use your votes on questions and answers that are well worded so that we seed the community with good cultural habits.

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-11-12**:
I'd upvote this answer but I don't have enough points.